# Bash grep keyword plus trailing numbers upto first whitespace

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I'm looking to filter tcpdump output and extracting only two constant element names and their string of changing numbers which is followed by a white space and more unwanted data. Is there a way to only extract up to the first white space using GREP of SED? I've been using bash for about a month and this is the first time my googlefoo has failed me.

```
Example output: red23:34:23 black23:43 purple00:55:22 yellow32:43 green10:10 (color names are constant) 

Looking to extract: black23:43 yellow32:43
```

Comment: Please do not use: `perl -anE'say for grep{/(black|yellow)\d+:\d+/}@F'<<< 'red23:34:23 black23:43 purple00:55:22 yellow32:43 green10:10'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The -o option in grep prints only the matching part, so to get just black and the numbers you might do this:

```
output='red23:34:23 black23:43 purple00:55:22 yellow32:43 green10:10'
echo "$output" | grep -Eo 'black[0-9]+:[0-9]+'
```

and you could parameterize it like so:

```
color='green'
echo "$output" | grep -Eo "${color}[0-9]+:[0-9]+"
```

Comment: I knew there was a simple way, this worked perfectly thank you!